# Train model by slicing train dataset(basically load few portion of data, train and unload again load another portion train and unload again repeat)

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, large-data

I have dataset of about 400k images (for training only separate dataset for validation and testing).

If I train model using 30k images (after gray scaling and cropping up to 256*64 pixel),
it takes up about 25GB of RAM, sometimes it spikes up to 30GB while running fit model obviously.
If lets say 30k images consumes 25GB of RAM (feasible for me) in average, I need 333.333GB of RAM and maybe more while fitting model which is not feasible in local run. Also I do not want to rely on cloud computing(which I think google is giving 90 day $300 free trail, but nah I want a solution that can work longer) cause I am broke.

So the Question is: **Is there any way to train a model by slicing those training data and do rinse and repeat with load-train-unload data?**

I was thinking of using libraries like crème through which we can stream data. But I do not think. It works for my project.

Also, if there is a solution can you please share a link to article with guide(if possible.)
Few lines of code example would be great too.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: How are you currently saving your images? Numpy? Could it be an idea to do all the preprocessing first, save all the images to a Numpy array with dtype `np.uint8` and then load this array for use in the ML model?

Comment: let me try that and see how much does this improve. tqs

Comment: `import numpy as np; imgs = np.random.randint(0,256, size=(400000,256,60), dtype=np.uint8); print(round(imgs.nbytes / 1024 / 1024,2), 'MB')`. 400 000 images takes up `5859.38 MB`.